# getting the Width of an element without padding in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, mootools

I want to fit images on my site to the size of their containing element, so I have this:

```
if (userHasMicrositePhoto) {
    var width = $('micrositePhotoDiv').getComputedSize().width;
    $('micrositePhoto').src = "flash/userImage.ashx?type=micrositePhoto&id=" + userId + "&width=" + width;
}
```

My handler file userImage.ashx returns the image given by the ID, scaled to the width given as a parameter.

This works fine in firefox, chrome & co, but doesn't work in Internet explorer - the image returned is too large. I think this is because `.getComputedSize().width` reports a width that includes the size of the padding (but on the border or margin) in Internet explorer, but returns only the usable area in other browsers. As a result, the width given by internet explorer is too large.

I can't find any other fields accessable for`.getComputedSize()` that allows me to find the 'actual' width in Internet Explorer. I tried using `.getComputedStyle()` to get the padding so I could subtract it from the total width, but this returns a string, and I am styling the `micrositePhotoDiv` element as `padding: 0.75em`, so this doesn't work.

What do I need to do to get the right width in internet explorer?

Comment: still..no answer here to this riddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the padding 0, but checking computed styles for sizes and positions is often buggy and hard to reconcile acreoss browsers.

Use offsetWidth or clientWidth instead, on all browsers.

Comment: I can't really set no padding for this element, and offsetWidth and clientWidth report the wrong (larger) size in both firefox and IE. Is there no way around this?

Comment: "These aren't the answers you're looking for"

Answer (score 3):

**jQuery** [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) does just that (see [jQuery source code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.fn.width)).

As you saw, usually `getComputedStyle` returns the width in pixels, so you can often do (except on old IE):

```
var width = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(elem).width);
```